# Ruby on Rails, issues using enum with same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

Here is some of the drop down in my view:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <%= f.select(:require_booking, get_advance_booking.collect {|p| [ p[:require_booking], p[:require_booking] ] }, {include_blank: false} , :class => 'form-control') %>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <%= f.select(:instant_booking, get_instant_booking.collect {|p| [ p[:instant_booking], p[:instant_booking] ] }, {include_blank: false} , :class => 'form-control') %>
</div>
```

and here is my `application_helper.rb`

```
  def get_advance_booking
    ret = [{:require_booking => 'No'},{:require_booking => 'Yes'}]
  end

 def get_instant_booking
    ret = [{:instant_booking => 'No'},{:instant_booking => 'Yes'}]
  end
```

But now the issue is, in my model `product.rb`, I can't set enum with same name:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum require_booking: {
        No: 0,
        Yes: 1
    }
    enum instant_booking: {
        No: 0,
        Yes: 1
    }
end
```

The error that I receive is `You tried to define an enum named "instant_booking" on the model "Product", but this will generate a instance method "No?", which is already defined by another enum.` How to resolve such a conflicts?

Comment: Use boolean values instead. There's no reason for these fields to be enums.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, just like the Marek Lipka said, you should use boolean value to handle your case.

If you need to define different enums with same entries, I suggest using the gem 'enumerize' (https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) instead.

## Update

Enum(https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) is supported in recent rails, and we should use it instead.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the :_prefix or :_suffix options when you need to define multiple enums with same values. If the passed value is true, the methods are prefixed/suffixed with the name of the enum. It is also possible to supply a custom value:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:active, :archived], _suffix: true
  enum comments_status: [:active, :inactive], _prefix: :comments
 end
```

source :http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Thanks! Wow. I accidentally erase some model files and i run a migration. After that, i couldn't restart anything because i was receiving an error about the enum was created before. I used _suffix: true on all of them and now are working. Thank you man.